# Crystal Report, Grouping Rows into single Row on the basis of Criteria

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report, which shows different fruits data on the basis of Fruit Name Group.

I am attaching a screen shot which tells the clear requirement, I want to group same type of fruits merge all into one rows and sum of their values as well.

I need help, can someone suggest a better idea?
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: how are you differentiating same type of fruits and different types of fruits?

Comment: This is the thing I wanted to ask that if the Text of the Field is = Oranges OR Lemon OR Grape Fruit then,I must concatinate them into one field and like wise on the baises of this, I take sum of them into a variable

Answer (score 1):

```
I am  not able to understand completely you problem.. but try below solution: If it is useful use it else discard
```

Concatenate Fruit Names: Create one formula `@Fruit`

```
Local StringVar orange;
Local StringVar Lemon;
Local StringVar Grape;

if <<databasefield.fruitname>>="Orange"
then orange:=<<databasefield.fruitname>>
else if <<databasefield.fruitname>>="Lemon"
then Lemon:=<<databasefield.fruitname>>
else  if <<databasefield.fruitname>>="Grape"
then Grape:=<<databasefield.fruitname>>;
orange+Lemon+Grape;
```

Summing the values: Create one formula `@Weight`

```
Local NumberVar orange;
    Local NumberVar Lemon;
    Local NumberVar Grape;

    if <<databasefield.fruitname>>="Orange"
    then orange:=<<databasefield.Weight>>
    else if <<databasefield.fruitname>>="Lemon"
    then Lemon:=<<databasefield.Weight>>
    else  if <<databasefield.fruitname>>="Grape"
    then Grape:=<<databasefield.Weight>>;
    orange+Lemon+Grape;
```

Edit:------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
you need to have grouping something like below.

```
Fruit name  Fruit Type
Orange       a
Grape        a
peach        b
apples       c
```

now when you group by `fruit type` and apply the formula I have provided then you can get desired results

Comment: I have added the formula and it combines, but repeating concatinating string for each fruit ( Lemon,Orange, Grape Fruit), How may i show distinct and also sum up like above screen shot?

Comment: For your requirement.. you need to have some filed that links fruit names and types.. then when you group by type you can concatinate the fruit name in that group... else it would be diffcult. Check my edited answer for idea on how should be the links

Answer (score 1):

1) Add a `Formula Field`

This formula field, should return
  - real `FruitName` for the cases you don't want to group,
  - a fake `FruitName` for the rows you want to group together.

Something like this (drag'n drop fields into Formula editor):

```
if {commandname.FruitName} <> 'Orange' AND  FruitName <> 'Lemon' 
   AND  FruitName <> 'Grape Friut' then  {commandname.FruitName}
else   'Orange, Lemon, Grape Friut'
```

2) use `Group Expert` to create a Group based on the new `Formula Field`

3) suppress details and show in `Group Header` or `Group Footer` `Totals` for each field

Comment: I am not getting your steps, I have added a formula field and now then copy-paste the code but its not giving me an option to right.

Comment: This is just a sample not good for copy - paste. Look at the edit and change part marked by {} dropping fields from your command or query

Answer (score 1):

I have done with other way, calculated these fruits values as a separate row, sum up all the values and then applying union , In union I have concatenated the fruit names using COALESCE function